# Posting xml file to ftp server in android

Tags: android, xml, ftp, posting

I want to send XML file to FTP Server.
Any one done this before? 
Please give useful links or code.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial:

http://www.javabeat.net/tips/36-file-upload-and-download-using-java.html

It shouldn't be too hard to port it to android (you might need to adapt some classes that might not exist in android's java environment)

Comment: Hey Thanks for quick reply...
I will try this link & will back with result.

Comment: I tried but it says unknown host.

But I found something else now it is working.
Thanks for your help.